# Is tos.html some kind of standard Terms of service filename?

Tags: url, standards, terms-of-use, filenames

I periodically check my log of 404 errors on my site, and aside of most curious hack attempts I often encounter requests for files that are some kind of standard on a specific platform (apple-touch-icon-`SIZE`x`SIZE`-precomposed.png is one of them).

And I have just found failed request for tos.html. When I searched it on google, it automatically searched for key "Terms of service", which has led to many terms of service pages, but no information about this kind of filename.

I'm quite curious if there's a word for files that should be on the site (index.php, favicon.ico, robots.txt - I couldn't find any relevant tag for this question)

Comment: Invent one :)  Someone does with every word

Answer (score 1):

It's not *standard*, but it is common.   Here are the terms of service URLs for some popular sites:

- [www.google.com/accounts/TOS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS)
- [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service)
- https://twitter.com/tos
- https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms
- https://about.pinterest.com/en/terms-service
- [en.wordpress.com/tos/](http://en.wordpress.com/tos/)
- https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms
- https://zynga.com/legal/terms-of-service

Not a *single one of them* uses your exactly URL.   However many of them do abbriavite it to "tos" (either capitalized on uncapitalized).

Whether it is called "tos.html" or "terms.html" or "Terms-Of-Service", [every website should have one](http://www.freshbooks.com/blog/2014/07/08/does-my-website-really-need-a-terms-and-conditions-page/).

Comment: Well, yeah I know that this abbreviation exists and is widely used. I already noted that in question. The thing that bugs me that some application automatically tried to retrieve it (our site is not an English site, so manual user input is not very likely).

Comment: Some programs such as AdSense require that you have a terms of service on your site.   It might make sense for them to try to fetch it at a common URL.